# Number of Rows in Gridview datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, count

I need to find and display the number of rows returned by the query.  This query is made using an SQLDataSource object, which is bound to an asp.net GridView control.  How can I find this information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the `Rows` property on the grid, because that only gives you what the GridView is currently rendering.  You need to hook up to the Selected event on the SqlDataSource and then you can pull the AffectedRows property.

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selected(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e) {
    int totalRows = e.AffectedRows;
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  I don't have to hit database again and I don't have to worry about the format of my datasource.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you handle the [SQLDataSource.Selected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selected.aspx) event and check the e.AffectedRows property.  It returns the number of selected rows.  Also, it is possible to obtain this information programmatically:

```
    DataView dv = (DataView)SQLDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    int rowCount = dv.Count;
```

NOTE: this code will result in selecting data once again.  So, the best solution is to use the Selected event for this purpose.

Comment: Hitting the database a second time just for a count?  Definately NOT worth it.